# how to show that there is no surjective function from a set to the set of natural numbers.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

So if I had a set $ A=\{1,...n\}$ where n is a positive integer how would I  show there is no surjective function from $A\rightarrow \mathbb{ N }$

I know that to show a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective you take an element $y$ where $y\in Y$ and show that $y=f(x)$ for some $x \in X$.

So I tried something like a proof my lecturer did, saying there was a set $D = \{a \in A | a\notin f(a) \}$

Then saying if $a\in D $  then $a\notin f(a)$ so $f(a) \neq D$ and doing something simmilar for $a\notin D$,
 and concluding that f is not a surjective function.

But this seamed very wrong looking at what I wrote thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint. Write down all the elements in the range of $f$ and find something not there.

Comment: You're hot to show it? :-)  Is it not possible to consider the set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n+1\} \subset \mathbb{N}$ and find the preimage, and apply the pigeonhole principle to show that there must be an element in the preimage that must be in there twice?

Comment: Take any function $f:A \to \mathbb N$.  Consider this function, $m: A \to \mathbb N$ defined recursively as $m(1) = f(1)$ and $m(k+1) = m(k)$ if $f(k+1) \le m(k)$ but $m(k+1) = f(k+1)$ if $f(k+1) > m(k)$.  In other words $m(j)$ is the max of all $f(k); k \le j$.  And $m(n)$ will be the max of all $f(k); k \le n$.   Then there is no $j \in A$ so that $f(j) = m(n) + 1$.  So $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks fleablood!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can't be surjective since it can't reach more than $n$ elements.

To prove that you can consider any $$f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{ N }$$

then consider $max(f)$ which exists since f has a finite number of elements, then consider $m=max(f)+1\in \mathbb{N}$ which is not reached by $f$, thus f is not surjective.

Comment: Thanks gimusi this really helped. :)

Comment: @user512254 You are welcome! Bye